# Undefined Variable $Member when trying to save data in my database phpmyadmin

Tags: laravel, controller

This is the controller code.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Member;
class membercontroller extends Controller {
    function addmemb(Request $req) {
        $member = new $Member;
        $member->name = $req->name;
        $member->age = $req->age;
        $member->email = $req->email;
        $member->save();
    }
}
```

View Code:

```
<h1>Enter The Member Info </h1>
<form action= "addmembers" method="POST">
    @Csrf
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name."> <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Enter Your Age.">  <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email.">  <br><br>
    <button type="submit">Add Member</button> <br><br>
</form>

Route::view('addmembers', 'addmembers');
Route::post('addmembers', [membercontroller::class, 'addmemb']);
```

These are the Routes for the view and functions. Can anyone point out my mistake? It's saying `Undefined Variable`.

Whenever I try to save data in my database it shows an error which says `$Member is undefined`. Please point out what should I do to make this run?

Answer (score 1):

$Member is not a Variable! its a model so you have to use it like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Member;

class membercontroller extends Controller
{
    
    function addmemb(Request $req){

        $member = new Member; ////////
        $member->name = $req->name;
        $member->age = $req->age;
        $member->email = $req->email;
        $member->save();
    }
}
```